# jquery table Sort multiple rows

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, sorting

Don't want to use any plugin for sorting table in jquery.

I have a html table, like this

[image]

On click of column name it should sort in desc order like this.

[image]

In example all are Table row only - Accord , Dutch, Status , Department , Invoice.

Dutch, Software , Status has Class name - Accord.

Inoive, Profit has Class name - Department.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/justinliang/Zhd2X/231/) according to your requirement. Pls check. Without any jQuery plugin.

Here is the js code of the main functionality:

```
$('th').click(function(){
    var table = $(this).parents('table').eq(0)
    var rows = table.find('tr:gt(0)').toArray().sort(comparer($(this).index()))
    this.asc = !this.asc
    if (!this.asc){rows = rows.reverse()}
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){table.append(rows[i])}
})
function comparer(index) {
    return function(a, b) {
        var valA = getCellValue(a, index), valB = getCellValue(b, index)
        return $.isNumeric(valA) && $.isNumeric(valB) ? valA - valB : valA.localeCompare(valB)
    }
}
function getCellValue(row, index){ return $(row).children('td').eq(index).html() }
```

Comment: in my case Accord is also tr only. but you have used as TH .